# Is building big portions of page in javascript bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On an existing project I am working on, I noticed many of the developers are building big portions of pages with javascript. For example:

```
$( targetdiv ).append("<div>");
$( targetdiv ).append("   <div class='info'>");      
$( targetdiv ).append("        <div id='modes'>");
$( targetdiv ).append("          <table cellspacing='0'>");
$( targetdiv ).append("            <tbody>");
// much more...
```

I understand using javascript to build **certain** elements on page. Sometimes the content is dynamic and it is now know when the page first loads (ajax stuff).

However, most of the code (not all is shown) is not dynamic and will be build the same way every time. No 'if' statements or loops

**Is there any reason why one would build large parts of pages using javascript vs just having the html be part of the html doc?** I would think one would want to minimize javascript html generation because its more confusing and harder to write. Also, javascript html generation has to hurt the performance (**Does it?**)

I am a "newer" javascript dev so maybe I am missing something. I want to say something but I am "newer" so maybe i don't get "it"

Thanks

Comment: `.append()` was not meant to receive invalid/incomplete strings of HTML, that won't work as you expect.

Comment: This looks like a painful way to develop.  I have never seen it.  The only reason I could imagine the purpose of this would be because separate teams develop code, and can't exchange code between them.

Comment: @SableFoste it's painful because it won't work :)

Comment: I wouldn't do this..change the DOM as little as possible!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7pDHk/

Comment: @Neal it does not work like `document.write()`. Look carefully it creates the entire element and not that specific line

Comment: @Neal no it doesn't work. eg tbody is supposed to be inside table

Comment: @Neal **NO.** `:)` http://i.imgur.com/YJ5H5ZF.png

Comment: @Spokey I ***never*** said it does the same as `document.write`

Comment: I cannot say why this development choice was made, but if dynamically injecting HTML is the goal, then the jQuery `.load()` function would be a better choice or if merging data with HTML constructs is necessary, then a templating solution work better too (i.e. Handlebars, jsRender, jTemplates, KnockoutJS, Underscore, etc.).

Comment: Letting alone the indentation in OP, `<tbody>` is not a valid direct child of `<body>` so it is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Neal yes you never did and you're right it is working the way `.append()` is supposed to, but it's obvious that the OP wanted it as `document.write()`

Comment: @Spokey ahhh I see that now.

Comment: Yes @Spokey worded it better than me. `;)` I wonder how come that no one suggested a templating engine yet.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I did suggest templating.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Oh my bad, I accidentally skipped just over your comment while replying to Neal. Yep those templating engines should take care of it better than manually building strings of static HTML. `=]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is quite possible [the most horrible way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hfYJsQAhl0) I have ever seen a kitten getting killed. Now, that's not just a kitten you killed: each line like this kills a thousands of kittens. And puppies.

Don't do this. It's wrong. It's bad. It's horrible. It's terrible. It's hell. It's anything but good.

On a more serious note...

1. The code doesn't even work as intended. See the comments on your question.
2. The HTML is the content, the JavaScript is the behavior. You're mixing both for absolutely no compelling reason.
3. Every time you call the DOM, you have time to go grab a coffee. You're calling `append` so many times that just seeing it hurts my eyes.

Comment: ***NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!*** Think of the children!!!

Comment: I figured it was bad. However, these are the same devs that use html ids like "1", "2",... I got work to do.

Comment: Aww comon man his code formatting looks so good :->

Comment: Totally agree. People who code like that are people who get paid by the line. Even if your resulting HTML is the same, it causes you to lose any ability to use a proper IDE, and the page will load more slowly than if it were a simple html file.

Comment: @timkomip Well that should tell ya something about them, shouldn't it?

Comment: @timkomip ID starting with number is valid in HTML5

Comment: @roasted There's an enormous difference between doing something because it's best practice and doing something because you can.  The only point when using numbers as ids could be useful is if it were generated by a library.

Comment: Well, though I'd hate to say this, I see one use case where this would be beneficial. Think of a large dynamic page that can't be cached, by putting HTML inside the JS you can easily achieve caching of such. inb4flamerain

Comment: @Neil sure! I was just trying to save some kittens...

Comment: So is it safe to say that one should try to use a small amount of appends as possible and leave as much html out of the javascript as possible? I mean an argument could be made that they are doing this because they want to be able to reuse the code in other places. But then again we are using django which includes a templating.

Comment: Well, as you implied: templating and code reuse go hand in hand. @Fabricio: Kinda true in a not-so-useful way. But if performance must be optimal and a developer is actually making the effort, then templates would be retrieved externally rather than embedded in the page, and those too can be cached.

Comment: @Katana314 that's right, however that's an extra request being made. Though with cache headers that could be cached too.

Answer (score 3):

From a philosophical standpoint, I would have to say this is a bad practice. `html` belongs in the `html` and that's it.

That said there are several different ways of adding html to the page via javascript.

```
<div id="template">
   <div class="mycontent">
      <!-- stuff -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Then

```
$('#target').append($('#template').html());
```

will give you the same results without having html code in your javascript.

---

But if you must (and sometimes you do) the most performant way is to create dom elements in native js and operate on them:

```
var template = document.createElement('div');
template.className = "mycontent";
// do more stuff to template
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(template);
```

---

The native js method while offering the best performance is hard on you as a developer. So if you wish to work with it as an html string, doing the append once would be best:

```
var template  = "<div class='mycontent'>";
    template +=    // add more string to build the template
    template += "</div>";

$('#target').append(template);
```

---

While ajax has a performance hit, as some suggested it is also an excellent way of managing your html code, allowing you to put the template in its own file. jQuery also has a shortcut to accomplish this:

```
$('#target').load('/template.html');
```

or if you wish to operate on the template:

```
$.get('/template.html', function(template){
    //do stuff to html
    $('#target').append(template);
}, 'html');
```

---

multiple append statements are with out a doubt the worst possible way to go, of all the less than great ways to go. Personally the first option I provided is my preference, and can easily be paired with libs like http://handlebarsjs.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Are you out of your mind :->, when you make a template assigning it an id is kind of stupid... no ?

Comment: AJAX is a better way.

Comment: @SableFoste should I flag your comment as being rude? I think it is.

Comment: @SableFoste eh ??? You can get values off ajax in json and still do client side templating

Comment: @Darkyen - no it is not stupid to assign an ID to a template piece of markup.

Comment: Not complex enough. You should load the html in JSON format from a database using server side code, then fetch it with an Ajax request, then parse it and finally you can insert it in the page.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine... It is not meant as rude or in Jest.  I would create a whole snippet in a separate HTML file, and just append via AJAX.  Of course, only if the program logic made sense (which it doesn't in this question, but that is assuming it could).

Comment: HAhahha you guys are the best. Sure ajax is a fine solution in many cases, but I am KISSing this.

Comment: @Renan `$.getJSON` and feed the data to a template. Simplified your comment a bit. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I like the `$.getJSON` approach very much with extra muchness, however I think the manner of template manipulation is outside the scope of this post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're new, it's a good thing you went to confirm your suspicions before taking action. That said, I'm pretty sure this is a case of lazy coding. In fact, there are actually even shorter ways of writing the code you posted, and those shorter ways won't delay the browser immensely.

For one thing, my favored way of writing large portions of the page is with a templating system - you put flat HTML files in your web directories, or in some sort of undisplayed portion of your page, and then import them when you need them to Javascript. A number of libraries can help with this.

But for goodness' sakes, even if you're too lazy to do it that way, do NOT do this with multiple append functions. That means the browser is figuring out new HTML elements and unclosed tags on each call of the function, often rewriting its own work. At the very least, append the HTML strings together bit by bit before calling jQuery.append ONCE.

```
var newHtml = "<div" +
  "   <div class='info'>" + ...
$(targetDiv).append(newHtml);
```